# how to sort dict and list in a way to keep mutual indexes coincide, python?

Tags: python

I have a following question:
if I have  a dictionary and list, for example:

```py
mydict = { “a” : url1, “b” : url2; “c” : url3; “d” : url4; “e” : url5}

mylist = [25, 76, 3, 8, 105]
```

5 elements each.

And I would like to sort the list

```py
mylist.sort()
```

I will have it like that:

```py
mylist = [3, 8, 25, 76, 105]
```

But what if I want to iterate both mdict and mylist  in parallel in a such way that original index0 of mydict would coincide with index0 of mylist , that is “a” : url1 would coincide to 25?
If I have it sorted, order would be broken…
After sorting “a” : url1  will coincide to 3 indexwise

Question is how to sort mydict and mylist in a way that indexes  would still coincide like in original order during the iteration in forloop?
 “a” : url1  →  25, b” : url2 →76, etc, but mylist should be sorted simultaneously, that is I have to sort mydict together with mylist somehow.

Comment: You might be interested to know that dictionaries are not inherently ordered in versions before 3.7 (I guess). And in dictionaries order does not really matter as you access values not by index but by their keys.

Comment: i have 3.7.2 so thats not my case. In the forloop it takes them from index 0 to index -1, so it is quite an equivalent

Comment: My point is even if you sort the dictionary, you are gonna access it's value by its key not the index.

Comment: not by indexes, it just an abstraction to better set the question(which ended up being bad idea). FOR cycle iterates them from start to end one by one and it keeps the order in 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use `OrderedDict` if you want to preserve the ordering. For your case the below code should work. Remember the `OrderedDict` preservers insertion order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = OrderedDict([('a', 'url1'), ('b', 'url2'),
                      ('c', 'url3'), ('d', 'url4'), ('e', 'url5')])

mylist = [25, 76, 3, 8, 105]

result_list, result_dict = zip(*sorted(zip(mylist, mydict.items())))

print(result_list)
print(OrderedDict(result_dict))
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thats what i neeed. Thanks a lot

Comment: What to do if on element of the list is None?